# Interview: Adding two binary numbers given as strings

Tags: c++, python, string, binary

While looking through some interview questions at http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Facebook-Interview-Questions-E40772.htm I came across the following question:

> Given two string representations of binary numbers (e.g. "1001", "10") write a function that adds them and returns the result as a string as well (e.g. "1011").

Here's some Python code that I started to write for the problem (it is incomplete right now), but I am not very sure if this is the best (or even correct) approach. I also thought about implementing the same in C++ first, but gave up considering the added complexities in string manipulations.

```
def add_binary(a,b):
    temp = ""
    carry = false
    //i from len(a) to 1 and j from len(b) to 1
    bit_sum = add_bit ((a[i],b[j])
    if (bit_sum == "10"):
            temp.append("0")
            carry = true
    elif carry:
            temp.append(add_bit("1",bit_sum))
    else:
            temp.append(bit_sum)

    return temp.reverse()


def add_bit(b1, b2):
    if b1 == '0':
            return b2
    elif b2 == '0':
            return b1
    elif (b1 = '1' and b2 =='1'):
            return "10"
    else return None

a = "1001"
b = "10"
add_binary(a,b)
```

Comment: `'{:b}'.format(int(a, 2) + int(b, 2))`

Comment: How large can they be?  The simplest solution is probably just to convert them to `int`, do the addition, and reconvert back, but this won't work if they can have hundreds of digits.

Comment: @eumiro: that's cheating.

Comment: @eumiro Ah, yes.  In Python, you can convert to and from binary, _and_ you have unlimited size (so your code should work even if the numbers have hundreds of digits).

Comment: @eumiro how about in C++?

Comment: It really isn't that hard. First pad the shorter number with zeros to match the longer numbers length. Then walk from the lowest bit, add the digits together, using a "carry" to remember if you have to carry over to the next digit. Add in the carry at the same time in the next iteration. Keep going until you reach the most significant bit, and if necessary, add a digit (if carry is set).

Comment: Cheating seems appropriate if you're told to solve this problem in Python, even in an interview. If the batteries are included, it's bad form to make your own instead. (Of course you should also know how to solve the obvious followup question of how to do it manually.)

Comment: The first step would be to ask the interviewer how negative numbers are represented. I for one wouldn't hire anyone who doesn't ask about that.

Comment: @thg435 Good point. (Although I'd consider this a trick question is you were looking for that answer.  Whether the candidate asks the question depends on too many irrelevant issues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the strings are short enough (less than 64 bits), I'd
probably just convert them to an internal integral type
(`unsigned long long`), do the addition there, and then
reconvert the results.  Converting between binary strings and
internal format is really, really trivial.

Otherwise, I'd probably first normallize them so that they have
the maximum length of the results.  Something like:

```
size_t size = std::max( lhs.size(), rhs.size() ) + 1;
lhs.insert( lhs.begin(), size - lhs.size(), '0' );
rhs.insert( rhs.begin(), size - rhs.size(), '0' );
```

I'd also create a results string of this size:

```
std::string results( size, '0' );
```

And a carry variable, initialized to '0':

```
char carry = '0';
```

I'd then loop over the three strings, using reverse iterators,
or more likely, just an index (which will ensure accessing the
same element of each string):

```
size_t current = size;
while ( current != 0 ) {
    -- current;
    //  ...
}
```

With in the loop, you really only have four possibilities: I'd
just count the '1's (in `lhs[current]`, `rhs[current]` and
`carry`), and do a switch on the results, setting
`results[current]` and `carry` appropriately:

```
int onesCount = 0;
if ( carry == '1' ) {
    ++ onesCount;
}
if ( lhs[current] == '1' ) {
    ++ onesCount;
}
if ( rhs[current] == '1' ) {
    ++ onesCount;
}
swith ( onesCount ) {
case 0:
    carry = '0';
    results[current] = '0';
    break;

case 1:
    carry = '0';
    results[current] = '1';
    break;

case 2:
    carry = '1';
    results[current] = '0';
    break;

case 3:
    carry = '1';
    results[current] = '1';
    break;
}
```

Personally, I think this is the simplest and the cleanest
solution, albeit a bit verbose.  Alternatively, you can replace
the switch with something like:

```
results[current] = onesCount % 2 == 0 ? '0' : '1';
carry = onesCount < 2 ? '0' : '1';
```

Finally, if desired, you can suppress any leading zeros in the
results (there will be at most one), and maybe assert that
`carry == '0'` (because if it isn't, we've screwed up our
calculation of the size).

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult part here is the fact that we need to process the strings from right to left. We can do this by either:

- Reversing the strings (input and output).
- In a recursive call, process the bits when "going back", i.e. first call a recursive add on the "next bits", then add the "current bit".
- Use reverse iterators and construct the result from right to left. A problem will still be how to know the resulting length in advance (so you know where to start).

The recursive solution has problems when the numbers are large, i.e. the stack might overflow.

Reversing the strings is the easiest solution, yet not the most efficient one.

A combination of the first and third option would be to process the input strings in reverse using reverse iterators, but construct the result in reverse order (so you can simply append bits), then reverse the result.

This is more or less also your approach. Implement the loop counting `i` and `j` from the string length minus 1 (!) until 0, so this will walk through the input strings in reverse order. If `carry` was set to true, add one to the bit sum in the next iteration. Represent the bit sum of `add_bit` as an integer, not as a string again, so you can add the carry.

In C++, you have the possibility to iterate through any sequence in reverse order using [rbegin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [rend()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend).

Comment: Reversing strings is cheap; if it makes the rest easier, use it.  I don't think it makes anything else easier.  Except maybe generating the results in reverse: you can use `push_back` for each digit, the reverse before returning.  But I think just constructing a results of all '0' with the maximum length is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

in Python you can convert strings to integers with `int`, which also allows a base for conversion:

```
num = '111'
print int(num, 2)
```

prints 7.

For converting the result back to binary:

```
print "{:b}".format(4)
```

prints 100

Comment: Any ideas on how this can be approached in C++?

Comment: depends if you can use third-party libraries.
There are implementations in C++ on stack overflow how to do it yourself, or boost lexical_cast if you can add third party things

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I don't think `boost::lexical_cast` can be made to work.  Part of the problem is that C++ doesn't have any conversions to or from binary strings.  (Another part is that the strings may be too long for the value to fit in any integral type, so you'd need some `BigInteger` class.)